# Наследование от потомков Throwable

Tags: java

При подготовке к тестированию встретил такой вопрос:
"От каких потомков класса Throwable нельзя наследоваться?"

На просторах всемирной паутины не нашел прямого запрета на наследование от каких-нибудь подклассов Throwable. Подумал что может есть запрет на наследование от Error. Проверил в javadoc, Error и его наследники public class.

Все таки есть запрет на наследование от какого-нибудь потомка Throwable?
Или запрета нет, но не имеет смысла наследоваться, при создании собственных исключений, например от Error?

Answer (score 1):

Классы-ошибки, расширяющие класс `Error`, свидетельствуют о возникновении сложных ситуаций в виртуальной машине Java. Их обработка требует глубокого понимания всех тонкостей работы JVM. Ее не рекомендуется выполнять в обычной программе. Не советуют даже выбрасывать ошибки оператором `throw`. Не следует делать свои классы-исключения расширениями класса `Error` или какого-то его подкласса.